# How to show progress bar in batch file while running sql

Tags: batch-file, stored-procedures, sybase

I am working right now a batch file that export data from database, I want to add/show a progress bar while exporting..

My code looks like this, it is running but no progress bar:

```
@TITLE TITLE HERE


@echo off

@ECHO           TITLE OF THE REPORTS

@echo.



set /p dsn=Please enter Datasource Name:  
dbisql -c "uid=dba;pwd=sql" -datasource %dsn%  -onerror exit export.sql 
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a second thread and check how big export.sql is, each time you update the progress bar.

When you don't know how big export.sql will be at the end, then a real progress bar (0-100%) will be hard.
You could first check how many rows you will export and then count the exported rows in export.sql each time in the progress bar thread.